# Up and down arrows are different hues

Tags: bug, design

The downvote arrow is darker grey than the upvote arrow. I was just browsing the site and thought to myself, “Huh? I don't recall downvoting that answer.” Then I remembered that the *actual* downvoted colour is a dark blue.

Up: #B4B4B4.
Down: #9F9F9F.

[image: Arrow screenshot]

I’m not at all sure how serious this is.

Comment: Obviously, the confusion is a bit worse on Meta since it uses grayscale.  (I take it that the "fiery red" for downvote was not implemented; I am mildly disappointed [even though I have never downvoted].)

Comment: Fiery red would be a clashing colour scheme. Mildly amusing, though. Perhaps it could be briefly fiery red, before reverting to dark blue? Or smite the answer with a hand of God effect (I can't find the site that does that now: you feed it a URL, and it gives you an image of the webpage which you can then smite; great fun).